# It is allowed to set a pointer as an value in a c# dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to define a dictionary where the key is of the string type and the value is a pointer. Is this possible in C#?

```
class Dictionary
{
     Dictionary<string, void*> hebrewWords = new Dictionary<string, void*>();

}
```

This code has an error.

Comment: This is impossible. Perhaps you can tell us what you are trying to do with such a dictionary, and we can suggest workarounds?

Comment: i am trying to make a program that every word in the dictionary will direct me to another place in a tree a am going to biled

Comment: How's your tree structure declared?

Comment: it is not declered yet, I thought blding it with classes that point at each other

Comment: See the edited answer. You don't need pointers at all. If you feel you really need pointers for whatever problem you are solving, perhaps the problem can be more easily solved with another language.

Comment: @Sweeper why this is impossible, could you explain?

Comment: @anatol The language specification _specifies_ that you cannot do this, hence this is not possible. Do you want to know _why_ the designers designed it this way? I suggest you post another question, but please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/is-asking-why-on-language-specifications-still-considered-as-primarily-opinio/323382#323382), and particularly [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293815/is-it-subjective-to-ask-about-why-something-wasnt-implemented-in-the-language/293819#293819), first.

Comment: @Sweeper I just cannot realize why we can declare `int*[]` but can't `List<int*>` f.e.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible. From the [language spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/unsafe-code#pointer-types):

> A `pointer_type` cannot be used as a type argument, and type inference (Type inference) fails on generic method calls that would have inferred a type argument to be a pointer type.

> i am trying to make a program that every word in the dictionary will direct me to another place in a tree

Well, your tree could be something like:

```
public class Node {
    public Node Left { get; set; }
    public Node Right { get; set; }
    // or a List<Node> if your tree is not binary
    public SomeType Data { get; set; }

    // constructor, Equals, GetHashCode...
}
```

Then your dictionary can be of type:

Dictionary<string, Node>